# LINQ Check ObservableCollection doesn't contain matching Object

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to check that my ObservableCollection doesn't have an object matching the one i'm trying to add.

For example:

```
public class LoggedUsers : NotifyUIBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Logged> UserList { get; private set; }
    public LoggedUsers()
    {
        UserList = new ObservableCollection<Logged>();
    }

    public void Add(Logged user)
    {
        if (UserList.Where(x => x == user))
        {
            UserList.Add(user);
        }
    }
}
```

So if the ObservableCollection has got a Logged object with the same property values as the `Add(Logged user)` then I want it to not add the `user`.

**Edit 1:**

```
public class LoggedUsers : NotifyUIBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Logged> UserList { get; private set; }
        public LoggedUsers()
        {
            UserList = new ObservableCollection<Logged>();
        }

        public void Add(Logged user)
        {
            if (!UserList.Any(x => x == user))
            {
                UserList.Add(user);

                ////Check the List for users
                UpdateView();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Already exists!");
            }
        }
```

**Edit 2:**
Changed my Logged class to the following:

```
namespace PhotoManagement
{
    public class Logged : Common.NotifyUIBase
    {
        public string ClearPassword { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public long UID { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        //Display basic statistics 
        public int ThisDayImageCount { get; set; }
        public int ThisDaySaleCount { get; set; }

        public Logged()
        {
            //Update the stats when instigated
            UpdateStats();
        }

        //Update the stats
        public void UpdateStats()
        {

        }

        public bool Equals(Logged other)
        {
            if (other == null) return false;
            return (this.UID.Equals(other.UID));
        }
    }
}
```

So this should work? However it still says Already Exists when I have checked the instances and they are different.

```
public class LoggedUsers : NotifyUIBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Logged> UserList { get; private set; }
        public LoggedUsers()
        {
            UserList = new ObservableCollection<Logged>();
        }

        public void Add(Logged user)
        {
            if (!UserList.Any(x => x.Equals(user)))
            {
                UserList.Add(user);
                UpdateView();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Already exists!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution is to implement **IEquatable** as said @vadim-martynov.

Another fast but no so clean solution is to search by explicitly comparing values:

```
public void Add(Logged user)
{
    if (!UserList.Any(x => x.Id == user.Id && x.UserName == user.UserName))
    {
        UserList.Add(user);

        ////Check the List for users
        UpdateView();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Already exists!");
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 1:**

Think about your **Logged** class. The key here is to implement the **IEquatable** interface who implement **Equals** method. There should you implement the **explicitly comparing** you will apply then we call *Equals* on this class.

```
public class Logged: IEquatable<Logged>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Logged other)
    {
        return this.Id == other.Id && this.UserName == other.UserName;
    }
}
```

After you Add method will look like:

```
public void Add(Logged user)
{
    if (!UserList.Any(x => x.Equals(user)))
    {
        UserList.Add(user);

        ////Check the List for users
        UpdateView();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Already exists!");
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2:**

Ok, then we must try a planb. Try implementing **IComparable** and try using with this. *IEquatable* should work but if not, this could work too.

```
public class Logged: IEquatable<Logged>, IComparable<Logged>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Logged other)
    {
        return this.Id == other.Id && this.UserName == other.UserName;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Logged other)
    {
        return this.Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
    }
}
```

IComparable returns int. So the usage and integer result are:

```
var result = x.CompareTo(user)    
//    Comparing 'some text' with '123': 1
//    Comparing 'some text' with 'some text': 0
//    Comparing 'some text' with 'Some Text': -1
```

Comment: How do I implement **IEquatable**? See Edit

Comment: That's what I expected, however I have done this but still getting the `Already exists` MessageBox show up :S I have tried adding a MessageBox to display a `user` property above the IF statement and the value IS different... :S

Comment: Ok @MartynBall I updated my answer again. Hope no help.

Comment: The issue there is that `(!UserList.Any(x => x.CompareTo(user)))` expects a bool not an int and it can't convert the int to bool.

Comment: Yes of course, now CompareTo returns an Integer and you should write some if else statement. I updated my answer to show how works CompareTo method.

Comment: I understand that but i'm using `Any()` to check all the objects in the ObservableCollection, which required a bool not an int. So how would I loop through these objects in the ObservableCollection now using LINQ?

Comment: You can use something like this: !UserList.Any(x.CompareTo(user) == 0)

Comment: I figured out the issue, the instance of the object I was binding to wasn't be notified of the update, this works now thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify the attribute in the query to find match, ex. Username or User ID.

```
public void Add(Logged user)
{
    if (!UserList.Any(u => u.Username == user.Username))
    {
        UserList.Add(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: See edit code, I get `Already exists!` when attempting to add a `Logged` instance with different values.

Answer (score 1):

By default your object compared by reference via `==` operator. It's common feature of reference types in c#.

You can [override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx) this operator or override `Equals` method.

> The new implementation of `Equals` should not throw exceptions. It is
>   recommended that any class that overrides `Equals` also override
>   `System.Object.GetHashCode`. It is also recommended that in addition to
>   implementing `Equals(object)`, any class also implement `Equals(type)` for
>   their own type, to enhance performance.

Also, you can [implement](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20592/Implementing-IEquatable-Properly) [`IEquatable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) for your `Logged` class.

> To avoid having different results depending on the way you check the
>   equality of the objects, you should override the `Object.Equals` method
>   in your class. This ensures that whenever a class doesn't use
>   the `IEquatable.Equals` method, still the same checks will be performed.

Finally you can compare some properties of 2 instances inside `Where` method:

```
if(!UserList.Any(u => u.Login == user.Login))
{
    UserList.Add(user);
}
```

Comment: You can't ***just*** override the `Equals` method. You must also always override `GetHashCode` too.

Comment: Yes it's the reason why I added a link to tutorial which helps to do it in the right way, mr. Minus.

Comment: Your answer should contain all the information it needs and links should only be to there to support the content in your question. External link answers are discouraged.